# How to get raw (un-decoded) byte arrays from a TCPSocket in Ruby

Tags: tcp, ruby

I've been using ruby to setup a TCPSocket with a server and I've hit a snag. When receiving data from the socket (with either a `socket.gets` or a `socket.recv`) I get something like this:

```
x00\x03!\xB2\x00\x00*\xCF
```

What I get when I capture the packets in Wireshark is

```
x00\x03\x21\xB2\x00\x00\x2a\xCF
```

As you can see, the `\x21` is decoded into the ASCII equivalent `!` and the `\x2a` is decoded into the ASCII equivalent `*`.

I've checked and googled a ton of times and have not yet found a solution to get the raw, un-decoded information. I have a parser built that will search for the relevant data from the stream and grab what I need, but I don't want to have to waste time re-encoding it before I have to decode it. Or, I incorporate ASCII into my parser, but that would be a huge pain. There is a lot of bytes in this stream and to re-encode them all would be time consuming. I also see that `netcat` returns the same output from the TCP stream that ruby does. I could not figure out how to get `netcat` to output the un-decoded byte arrays either.

Code:

```
require 'socket'
s = TCPSocket.new "10.0.0.3", 27000

while true do
  item = s.recv(5000)
  puts item
  puts item.inspect
end
```

This is my first foray into socket programming, so I apologize if I missed something very obvious.

Comment: Yeah, I'm a total dummy. I stored the info as `s.recv(5000).inspect` instead of `s.recv(5000)` so ruby escaped the byte array delimiters thus `.pack` wouldn't work on it. When I saved the info regularly, (unescaped), `.pack` worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

I kind of invented the problem in my head, I am dumb.

To solve this, all you need to do is take the string of TCP information and call `unpack("H*")` on it like this:

```
"x00\x03!\xB2\x00\x00*\xCF".unpack("H*")
=> ["7830300321b200002acf"]
```

Which is exactly like `x00\x03\x21\xB2\x00\x00\x2a\xCF`

Now I just need to adjust my parser to split it or deal with the big clump of byte arrays

[More info on unpack](http://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/String:unpack)